# Difference Between Attention and Fully Connected Layers in Deep Learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, rnn, attention-mechanism

There have been several papers in the last few years on the so-called "Attention" mechanism in deep learning (e.g. [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473)). The concept seems to be that we want the neural network to focus on or *pay more attention* to certain features, and has demonstrated some empirical success in NLP and related sequential models.

When I look at some code examples such as this [one](https://analyticsindiamag.com/hands-on-guide-to-bi-lstm-with-attention/#:%7E:text=basic%20lstm%20gets%20confused%20between,represented%20by%20the%20above%20image.), adding an Attention layer intuitively makes sense and seems to improve performance of the LSTM model. However it looks very much like a regular fully-connected layer. In that link (and with some slight change of notation), the Attention layer outputs
$$ c(x) = \tanh(\mathbf{W}x + \mathbf{b} ) $$
$$ \beta(x) = \frac{e^{c(x_j)}}{\sum_{j} e^{c(x_j)}} $$
$$ f_{Attention}(x) = x\beta $$
where $W,b$ are weights/biases, $x$ is layer input, and $f(.)$ is the layer output. In contrast, a regular fully connected layer:
$$ f_{Dense} = \sigma(\mathbf{W}x + \mathbf{b}) $$
for some activation function $\sigma(.)$.

My interpretation of the Attention implementation above is that it is pretty much the same thing as a standard fully connected layer, but with a $\tanh$ activation (why?), followed by a $\text{softmax}$ (okay, so that the "attention weights" $\beta$ sum to 1), followed by a linear dot product.

How does this architecture allow the model to have "attention"? I do not see how it is fundamentally different or more expressive from just adding a standard fully-connected layer. Am I misunderstanding something here?

---

**Edit/My Interpretation**

I looked at the code example closer and there is in fact a difference due to the shapes of the parameters.

For an input $X$ with shape `(N,T,K)` where $N$ is samples, $T$ is time, and $K$ is features, the shapes of the Attention parameters are: $W$ `(K, 1)`, $b$ `(T,1)`. This implies that both the "context" $c$ and "attention weights" $\beta$ have shape `(N,T,1)`. Thus in the final dot product, we are using the Attention layer to **weight each timestep** (e.g. pay more attention to prices yesterday and 5 days ago, but less attention to 30 days ago).

In contrast, a fully connected layer in this context would generate some (unnormalized) weights **for each feature column** uniformly across timesteps (e.g. pay more attention to all prices, but less to interest rates).

Answer (score 0):

The attention mechanism is based on transformers that also include fully connected layers indeed.

The difference comes mainly from the RNNs that are the base of the attention mechanism. However, [this attention is quite limited](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/1524491101515694083).

It could be difficult to understand how it works precisely, even if you get the idea step by step.

That's why, a good way to understand how they work is to use playgrounds like those ones:

https://distill.pub/2016/augmented-rnns/

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/blob/master/tensor2tensor/notebooks/hello_t2t.ipynb#scrollTo=OJKU36QAfqOC

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.